# Chrome extension, switch browserAction onclick

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developping an extension and I would like to let the users choose if they want the browserAction button to open an HTML page in the popup or to open it in a new tab.

first case (in manifest):

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "data/button.png"
    },
    "default_page": "./popup/popup.html"
}
```

second case (in index.js):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() { window.open('../popup/popup.html', ...); });
```

Is there a way to switch between these two cases in the background script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`chrome.browserAction.setPopup()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setPopup). If you set the popup to `''`, no popup is shown:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: ''});
```

You can then set the popup back to a HTML page when you are wanting the popup:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: '/myPopup.html'});
```

A convenient thing is that if a popup is shown, the `browserAction` event is not fired.  Thus, the tab will not open. This switches between the two by either setting the `browserAction.setPopup()` to `''`, or not.